# How to turn off the screen after a period of time?

Tags: android, keyguard, android-powermanager

To unlock the screen in my service, I used `disableKeyguard` method in `KeyguardManager`.

```
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock  kl = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
kl.disableKeyguard();
```

However, it also removes the auto sleep/turn off my screen. I want to maintain the option. It means that the screen will be turned on using above code, then if the user does not press anything to screen, it will auto turn off after a period of time. I know a method to reenable the keyguardManager as  `kl.reenableKeyguard();`, but it has to call somewhere. Thank you so much

Comment: How about using `CountDownTimer`? Start timer when user start app. And reset the timer each time user touch the app. But after some period of time user don't touch the app, reenable the keyguard.

Comment: It is good one method, but we do not know the setting of user. For example, someone set screen off after 30 seconds, 10 seconds... It depends on user setting also